# How to get id from object in ngFor to be used for id lookup in database (Angular)?

Tags: angular

> I have a webpage of articles that I grab from my database and put into
>   an array and then display using an `ngFor`. On each article, I have a
>   'View Details' button. I want to be able to click that button and then
>   be taken to `/articles/{articleId}`. I am trying to do that by
>   grabbing the id of the article that is clicked (View Details is
>   clicked on an individual article), but I am not sure on how to grab
>   that id when the button is clicked. I've seen to use the `Input` and
>   pass the data from parent to child, but I'm not sure how to get that
>   to work when using an ngFor, or if this idea of passing the data is
>   even a good way.My idea currently is to grab the id and then pass it
>   to a child component which then uses my `findById` function to grab
>   all the data about the article and then show that article in that
>   child component (`/article/{articleId}`
>
> Child Component:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from "@angular/core";
import {Article} from "../article.model";
import {ArticlesService} from "../articles.service";
import {ActivatedRoute, Params} from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-view-articles',
  templateUrl: './view-articles.component.html'
})
export class ViewArticlesComponent implements OnInit {
  article: Article;
  id: string;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private articleService: ArticlesService) { }

  // this is where I would used the passed id to pass into findArticle but an id is hardcoded in right now
  ngOnInit() {
    this.articleService.findArticle("59dcba5fae3c751b45665ca7")
        .subscribe(
            (article: Article) => {
              this.article = article;
            }
        );
  }

}
```

> Article Service findArticle function (called from child component)

```
  findArticle(id: string) {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/article/' + id)
        .map((response: Response) => {
          const article = response.json().obj;
          let transformedArticle: Article = new Article(article.author, article.title, article.body, article._id);
          return transformedArticle;
        })
        .catch((error: Response) => {
          this.errorService.handleError(error.json());
          return Observable.throw(error.json());
        });
  }
```

> Parent Component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {ArticlesService} from "./articles.service";
import {Article} from "./article.model";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-articles',
  templateUrl: './articles.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./articles.component.css']
})
export class ArticlesComponent implements OnInit {
  articles: Article[];

  constructor(private articleService: ArticlesService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.articleService.getArticles()
        .subscribe(
            (articles: Article[]) => {
              this.articles = articles;
            }
        );
  }

}
```

> Parent HTML

```
<div class="row">
  <!--/span-->
  <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4"
       *ngFor="let article of articles">
    <h2>{{article.title}}</h2>
    <h4>By: {{article.author}}</h4>
    <p>{{article.body}}</p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#">View details »</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko no problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use routerlinks eg.

```
<div class="row">
  <!--/span-->
  <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4"
       *ngFor="let article of articles">
    <h2>{{article.title}}</h2>
    <h4>By: {{article.author}}</h4>
    <p>{{article.body}}</p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-default" [routerLink]="['/articles',article.id]">View details »</a></p>
  </div>
```

and or if you prefare create a function..

```
goToArticleDetails(id) {
  this.router.navigate(['/articles', id]);
}
```

Comment: That sounds like a great idea (I think I've been overthinking this), but how would I then grab that article.id to use in my child component?

Comment: Check [this](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/routing/routeparams.html) example, it will guide you through this.

Comment: Awesome. It will take me a little bit to configure this (cause I'm a newbie), but from the looks of it, it is exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Articles page:

```
<a class="btn btn-default" (click)="viewDetails(article.id)">View details</a>

import { Router } from '@angular/router';

viewDetails(_id){
   this.router.navigate(['/article/'], { queryParams: { id: _id } });
}
```

Article page:

```
import {Router, ActivatedRoute, Params} from '@angular/router';
import {OnInit, Component} from '@angular/core';
import {ArticlesService} from "./articles.service";
import {Article} from "./article.model";

@Component({...})
export class ArticleComponent implements OnInit {
  article: Article;
  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
        let id = params['id'];
           this.articleService.findArticle(id).subscribe(
               (article: Article) => this.article = article;
           );
      });
  }

}
```